# Sending an SMS to a Cellphone using Django

Tags: django, sms, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I am building an application, where I have this little survey module, which sends out a simple sms to the phone number I give and has to collect the response(if the user fires it) and show it to me. I am using to django build my project. I have tried django-sms google code project, but I couldn't post messages back from my mobile to my server. I have browsed through many tutorials on sms-gateways/carriers. But I am lost. Can anyone help me in suggesting a tutorial about sending sms from my application(django) to any cellphone? And regarding sending sms to cellphone, would it cost me(just as how i send sms from one cellphone to another)?

Answer (score 22):

Hi my name is Jarod and I work for Twilio.com so I am a little biased. But with that said, it is super easy to send an SMS from your Python web application using the [Twilio Rest Api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon). Here is a simple example:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install 
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "{{ account_sid }}"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    body="Jenny please?! I love you <3",
    to="+15558675309",
    from_="+14158141829",
    media_url="http://www.example.com/hearts.png")
print message.sid
```

Comment: this service is pretty cool. i just signed up and played around with it... but it costs money, eh? $1 a month and per message fees?

Comment: before I sign up, do you have any stackoverflow special promo codes? :) :)

Comment: I am also trying to use twillo but I have to wait a long time for twillo to confirm my phone number, and currently, the twillo has not sent me a confirmation message. Very bad library

Comment: When I saw the body of the message, the first thing I checked was the phone number... I was born in '98... One day no one will know this reference.

Answer (score 11):

From a technical standpoint, the easiest way to accomplish SMS sending with any web-app is through e-mails.  Most cell providers usually give out email accounts to their users, and sending a mail to said account will more likely than not redirect the mail to their cell via SMS.  However, not all carriers do this and some charge extra for this type of service.  In this case, you could handle this checking out the following [Django documentation page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/)

However, as mentioned, this isn't a really complete solution, so the easiest way would be to use a SMS-gateway.  Mostly, they provide simple REST based API's for sending text messages to cell phones.  The API would vary obviously from carrier to carrier.  I would recommend checking out [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) in case you're looking for a free and open source solution (that is assuming you want to install the actual gateway on your server).

Anyway, I would start out trying to get it to work with the e-mail scenario, and then moving on to using a carrier if you actually require it.  Hopefully this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a similar question, a bit late to the game, in another post. Here it is for additional information. Hope it helps:

I was struggling with this for some time and really liked the Twilio option. But then I dug deeper and found that there is a Google Voice API called `pygooglevoice` that works. Clean, easy... No carrier lookup... For example, set up a [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) and install with `pip`:

`pip install pygooglevoice`

Then use something like this:

```
from googlevoice import Voice
from googlevoice.util import input

def send(number, message):
    user = 'user@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'

    voice = Voice()
    voice.login(user, password)

    #number = input('Number to send message to: ') # use these for command method
    #message = input('Message text: ')

    voice.send_sms(number, message)
```

Please note that I have done limited testing with this so I'm not sure all the pros and cons. It's quite possible that there are limitations I haven't discovered yet. But in the time I've played around with it, I've been happy.

Comment: I have been trying to use pygooglevoice but keeps getting errors no matter which version of the module or python's. can you please share your environment settings or a requirements.txt file if using a virtual env?

Comment: @Olfredos6 You should be able to test this with a module similar to the one I added above. If you install `pygooglevoice` from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pygooglevoice/), you should get its dependencies, which are the important ones here.. You could also try [`googlevoice`](https://pypi.org/project/googlevoice/) which is based on the former.

Comment: unfortunately, Google's Voice is only available in the U.S

Comment: and Voice for work is only available in a few countries. https://support.google.com/voice/answer/9310722

Answer (score 3):

take a look at [django-sms](http://code.google.com/p/django-sms/)

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't post messages back from my mobile to my server.

Comment: i think my main concern with this kind of app is the carrier info. if you only know the number, can you find out the carrier code email to actually send smtp messages? i'm reading it now, so if this is answered, i'm sure i'll find it. thanks.

Comment: Is this free? what's the catch

Answer (score 0):

Check out [twilio.com](http://twilio.com). They provide easy to use API (couple of lines of code in Python) and possibility to receive SMS messages and firing callbacks in your application when users respond.

Answer (score 0):

http://bitbucket.org/vgavro/django-smsgate is obviously what you are looking for, but you have to write custom backend for your sms-gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found [TextMagic](https://www.textmagic.com/docs/api/python/). It looks promising although it is a bit pricey for the country I live in. It may have competitive prices for the country you are interested in, so **please check pricing before you charge ahead.**

Usage seems to be easy enough:

Quick installation via pip:

```
pip install textmagic
```

And sending an SMS seems to be trivial as follows:

```
from textmagic.rest import TextmagicRestClient

username = "your_textmagic_username"
token = "your_apiv2_key"
client = TextmagicRestClient(username, token)

message = client.messages.create(phones="9990001001", text="Hello TextMagic")
```

Comment: Looks simple to use but doesn't cover many countries. Twilio has the widest coverage so far