# Use phone number to authenticate user in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a method for me to correctly use a user's phone number as a login/authenticate mechanism in Django? Till date I've used Django's in built auth system so I've never come across such a requirement.

However, now that I have, I can't seem to make any progress apart from figuring out that I'd have to use a One Time Password mechanism on sign up to authenticate.

Comment: Try some thing like `auth using username` and put phone number there

Comment: Do you mean like send a text message to a phone number with a 1-time initial password?

Comment: @mfcovington, yes. Django is being used in the backend for a phone application. So the client requires authentication by phone only.

Comment: I'd start by checking out these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430582/sending-an-sms-to-a-cellphone-using-django https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/building-a-simple-sms-message-application-with-twilio-and-django-2.html https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/sms/

Comment: @mfcovington, What I want is that a user will be identified by a phone number. Not through anything else. Not exactly sending SMS, but actually identifying/logging in/registering with a phone number.

Comment: Ah, then the answer below should work.

Answer (score 11):

You can customize the `User` model and specify a different field be used as the username. This is mentioned in [the auth documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser):

> **USERNAME_FIELD**
>
> A string describing the name of the field on the User model that is used as the unique identifier. This will usually be a username of some kind, but it can also be an email address, or any other unique identifier. The field must be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition).

so something like:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.RegexField(...)
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
```

You should read through the authentication documentation, specifically ["Customizing the User model"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and ["Substituting a custom User model"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

Just implement a custom authentication backend. Django has an example [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/) using the email field. Just do the same but with a phone number field.

Comment: Every time you say "just" double the cost and triple the time.