# How to send SMS and Email Notifications to User When Logged In using Django

Tags: python, django, email, sms

I am currently working on a project that needs to send SMS and Email messages to users when they either logged in, or their status needs to be notified. I am doing this with Django 1.9. I've tried django-notifier but then I realized it's just for email. Is there anyway I could do both using only 1 django function. If there is, I would really appreciate if you could give me links on how to do it. Thanks!

This is different because I need to send an SMS and EMAIL in django.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817279/1418794), maybe it helps.

Comment: I've tried this...it doesn't work. Thanks though @doru

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an SMS to a Cellphone using Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430582/sending-an-sms-to-a-cellphone-using-django)